# Removing builtin modules in Linux

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers, usb, modprobe

I'm currently attempting to remove the usbserial module in order to install a new driver module. When I attempt to remove the module I get the following issue:

```
[root@localhost xr21v141x-lnx-3.0-pak]# modprobe -r usbserial
FATAL: Module usbserial is builtin
```

How can I remove the usbserial module?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That means the module was compiled into the kernel.  If you want to be able to unload it, you will have to compile a new kernel and have it built as a dynamically (un)loadable module instead.

Comment: Does this mean it's impossible to install a new driver module which uses usbserial?

Comment: A module which *uses* usbserial will be fine.  One which is intended to *replace* usbserial -- I guess you can try, but as a guess I would say probably not.